# How to organize and share utility libraries/classes (not code snippets)

Tags: java, github, share, code-reuse

I have many many adhoc and general utility classes that I have written over the years in various projects. 
Some of them are wrappers/adapters to other libraries.

For Java its a challenge to share this code because each utility class may have very different dependencies (for example I have some classes that require *guava* and others *commons-lang*).

The obvious choice is to **github** my code and **blog** about it. Annoyingly I have make a project (Maven pom) for each utility class (not to mention lots of jars).

How do others share utility code (not full blow libraries)?

Comment: I also have unit tests for each of my utility classes (another reason why they are not code snippets).

Comment: **N.B.** I am very familiar with the commons* and google* utility libraries. My classes offer functionality that those libraries do not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they're things you just want to save, but don't want to make a full-blown project out of, try https://gist.github.com.  Bonus points if you blog about it too, you can embed the gist directly in your blog post.

Answer (score 1):

The Apache commons libraries provide a lot of utility classes.  They are grouped together into libraries with related functionality.  Perhaps you could contribute to these libraries to share your code.

Comment: I don't think you read my post very careful. I have utility classes that use Commons-Lang already.

Comment: @Adam Gent, I don't get what you are saying. I would have thought that would make using their approach, or contributing to those libraries more appropriate.

Comment: Oh looks like I didn't read your post well :) Don't I feel like the horses ass. Well I have tried to contribute but Apache is kind of slow in adoption... like really slow. They finally added some stuff I submitted 3 years ago.